# How can I install Boost Property Tree with conan?

Tags: c++, conan

I'm trying to install Boost's Property Tree library ("boost_property_tree/1.70.0@bincrafters/stable") but am not capable to do so, I always get an error saying it's not available:

```
C:\Users\RHPACHECO\Desktop\kv\CMakeBasedCore\kvcore\build (master -> origin)
(conanrunenv) λ conan install boost_property_tree/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable
Configuration:
[settings]
arch=x86_64
arch_build=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=Visual Studio
compiler.runtime=MD
compiler.version=15
os=Windows
os_build=Windows
[options]
[build_requires]
[env]

boost_property_tree/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable: Not found in local cache, looking in remotes...
boost_property_tree/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable: Trying with 'conan-center'...
boost_property_tree/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable: Trying with 'conantest'...
ERROR: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='10.157.5.1', port=9300): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/ping (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x04AEE3D0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))

Unable to connect to conantest=https://10.157.5.1:9300
```

Is there a specific remote I need to configure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is being caused by a connection error:

> ERROR: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='10.157.5.1', port=9300): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/ping (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))

The IP address showed is local, which mean Conan is looking for `boost_property_tree` in your local server (conan_server or Artifactory).

You can force a specific remote passing `--remote`

```
conan remote add bincrafters https://api.bintray.com/conan/bincrafters/public-conan
conan install boost_property_tree/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable --remote bincrafters
```

Conan will skip other remotes and try to find `boost_property_tree` in bincrafters' remote. This will solve your problem partially, you need to fix your local server. You could remove it from you remote list:

```
conan remote remove conantest
```

To have more information about Conan install:
https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/consumer/install.html#conan-install